# Shell Scripting - checking for file existence

Tags: arrays, shell

I'm trying to write a shell script that checks if 3 specific files exist in the folder. I also want to store the results in an array. Once the file checking is done, I want to check the array to make sure at least one (1) file exists before the script can continue.

A successful output should look like this:

```
File file1.sh..........OK!
File file2.sh..........NOT FOUND!
File file3.sh..........OK!
File check completed successfully.
```

A failed output should look like this:

```
File file1.sh..........NOT FOUND!
File file2.sh..........NOT FOUND!
File file3.sh..........NOT FOUND!
At least one file is required to continue.
```

Right now I am using if/else statements like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ -f file1.sh ]]; then
  echo "File file1.sh........OK!";
  isFILE1=1
else 
  echo "File file1.sh........NOT FOUND!";
  isFILE1=0
fi
```

However, I'd like to do something like this instead. And also make printing the result on the same line as the File file1.sh.......:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "File file1.sh.........";
if [[ -f file1.sh ]]; then
  echo "OK!";
  isFile[0]=1;
else 
  echo "NOT FOUND!";
  isFile[0]=0;
fi
```

I'm not sure how to check if at least 1 file in the array isFile exists.

Comment: Set a flag at the beginning: `some_file_found=0`. In the `[ -f "$file" ]` add `some_file_found=1` and finally check that value.

Comment: That solves if at least one file exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To keep the output on one line change this

```
echo "File file1.sh.........";
```

to

```
echo -n "File file1.sh.........";
```

The `-n` suppresses the new-line.

For checking the file existence from an array, use a singular flag and change it to `1` if you find a file.

Comment: I understand printf is better to use than echo from a POSIX standard.  Also, when using either echo -n or printf it seems to print the name of the shell file I'm running before the output. Is there anyway I can suppress it?

Comment: @Mark echo or printf isn't doing that, unless you've added the name of the shell file to the echo or printf.

Comment: I didn't specifically add it. Could it be a setting in .bash_profile? My output is: ./program.sh File file.sh......Ok